# AWS "Hello World" Python Lambda results in Runtime.ImportModuleError: "Unable to import module"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I've read dozens of articles, blog posts, docs, and Q&A posts on this site on this issue, and I haven't found a solution.

My Python code in `index.py` is simple:

```py
def handler(event, context):
    print("hello world. this is hello handler")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hello world. this is the main section in hello index.py")
```

Notice that I'm using the default filename `index.py` and the default entry point `handler`.

I have a simple pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "hello"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~3.9"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.1.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

As a basic sanity check, I can run the main section locally via:

```sh
poetry run python index.py
```

I deploy via typescript CDK:

```js
    const stack = new Stack(app, "PythonHelloStack", {env})
    new PythonFunction(stack, `HelloFunction`, {
        runtime: Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
        entry: path.join(__dirname, `../../../lambdas/hello`),
    })
```

This successfully creates the Lambda. When I run a test event against this, I get the error:

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'index'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
```

To show a screenshot of the console, which shows the code:

[image: screenshot of Lambda console]

The code shows up fine if I click on `index.py`. Why can't the AWS Lambda import `index.py`? I'm stuck on how to proceed in troubleshooting this.

Comment: Maybe your path in`path.join` is incomplete? Try pointing it to the `py` file.

Comment: But the `index.py` file is uploaded correctly. See the screenshot at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is a bug in CDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18301) that's still to be patched in the next release. Downgrade to `1.136` if using CDK v1, or the `2.3.0-alpha.0` version of `@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-python-alpha` if using CDK v2.

**UPDATE:** The [1.139 CDK release](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/releases/tag/v1.139.0) fixes the issue.

Comment: Wow, downgrading the CDK totally fixed it without changing anything else. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the handler info in runtime setting. Handler should be filename.functionname

if your filename is index.py and function name is handler then handler in the settings should be index.handler